# convert a string 11/28/2014 11:00 am to date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, date, format

I want to parse to Date in javaScript this 11/28/2014 11:00 am.

I tried `new Date("String") = NaN`
and

```
fecha_iniString=" 11/28/2014 11:00 am"
var dateString    = fecha_iniString.match(/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}/);
var dt            = new Date(dateString);
alert(dt);
```

The alert window shows

> wef dec 31 19:00:00 EST   1969

Comment: `.match()` returns an array.

Comment: Use http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Maybe you should look at this: [converting string to date in js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Comment: `new Date("11/28/2014 11:00 am")` works in Chrome.

Comment: Also, the regex looks for "dddd/dd/dd" but your string is "dd/dd/dddd".

Comment: Also also, the regex completely ignores the am/pm part of the string.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly And IE 11, and Firefox 31. Which browser doesn't it work on?

Comment: @JamesHunt IE8 I'd imagine.

Comment: forget `Date.parse` - `var d = new Date(); d.setTime(Date.parse("11/28/2014 11:00 am"));` What format u need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Date.parse`

```
var dateStr = "11/28/2014 11:00 am",
    date = new Date(), 
    date.setTime(Date.parse(dateStr));

var formDate = new Date(date);

console.log(formDate);
```